# Tsparticles library not rendering particles while using Laravel + Vite setup

Tags: javascript, laravel, vite, particles.js, laravel-10

I am trying to set up the [tsparticles library](https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles/) using Laravel and its default configuration of Vite. I followed the docs of what would be a "vanilla js" set up, since I am not using Vue, by:

- Running `npm install tsparticles-engine` (also tried the `tsparticles` full bundle)
- Importing the engine as `import { tsParticles } from "tsparticles-engine";` on my app.js
- Loading the particles with `tsParticles.load("tsparticles", <options>);` on my app.js
- Requiring the library with `@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])` on the blade file
- Adding the element `<div id="tsparticles" style="...codepen styles"></div>` on the blade file

After failing to use the official docs successfully, I used [this codepen](https://codepen.io/matteobruni/pen/oNXWapG) as an example to try an make it work, but the particles are not showing at all; the result is only a blue background. Yet it seems like the setup is correctly done:

- Inspecting the page elements does show the full-screen canvas element within the div
- The library correctly loads background color options if configured, just not the particles

My full set up is as follows, any help would be appreciated!

*resources/views/particles.blade.php* (the main view)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Aimentia</title>

    @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
</head>

<body>
    <div id="tsparticles" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #0d47a1; background-image: url(''); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: 50% 50%;"></div>
</html>
```

*package.json* (using tsparticles 2.9.3)

```json
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.2",
        "postcss": "^8.4.23",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.3.1",
        "vite": "^4.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "tsparticles": "^2.9.3"
    }
}
```

*resources/js/app.js*

```js
    import './bootstrap';
    import { tsParticles } from "tsparticles-engine";
    
    tsParticles.load("tsparticles", {
        fps_limit: 60,
        interactivity: {
          detect_on: "canvas",
          events: {
            onclick: { enable: true, mode: "push" },
            onhover: {
              enable: true,
              mode: "repulse",
              parallax: { enable: false, force: 60, smooth: 10 }
            },
            resize: true
          },
          modes: {
            bubble: { distance: 400, duration: 2, opacity: 0.8, size: 40, speed: 3 },
            grab: { distance: 400, line_linked: { opacity: 1 } },
            push: { particles_nb: 4 },
            remove: { particles_nb: 2 },
            repulse: { distance: 200, duration: 0.4 }
          }
        },
        particles: {
          color: { value: "#ffffff" },
          line_linked: {
            color: "#ffffff",
            distance: 150,
            enable: true,
            opacity: 0.4,
            width: 1
          },
          move: {
            attract: { enable: false, rotateX: 600, rotateY: 1200 },
            bounce: false,
            direction: "none",
            enable: true,
            out_mode: "out",
            random: false,
            speed: 2,
            straight: false
          },
          number: { density: { enable: true, value_area: 800 }, value: 80 },
          opacity: {
            anim: { enable: false, opacity_min: 0.1, speed: 1, sync: false },
            random: false,
            value: 0.5
          },
          shape: {
            character: {
              fill: false,
              font: "Verdana",
              style: "",
              value: "*",
              weight: "400"
            },
            image: {
              height: 100,
              replace_color: true,
              src: "images/github.svg",
              width: 100
            },
            polygon: { nb_sides: 5 },
            stroke: { color: "#000000", width: 0 },
            type: "circle"
          },
          size: {
            anim: { enable: false, size_min: 0.1, speed: 40, sync: false },
            random: true,
            value: 5
          }
        },
        polygon: {
          draw: { enable: false, lineColor: "#ffffff", lineWidth: 0.5 },
          move: { radius: 10 },
          scale: 1,
          type: "none",
          url: ""
        },
        retina_detect: true
      });
```

*vite.config.js*

```js
    import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
    import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
    
    export default defineConfig({
        plugins: [
            laravel({
                input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
                refresh: true,
            }),
        ],
    });
```